# Yahoo Finance: Is it legal to get the data (real-time) and put it on my website?

Tags: licensing, yahoo-finance, stocks

I figured out how to get real-time ("live" - EDIT: but delayed by 15 minutes) stock data from yahoo finance ...now the question is : is it legal to put the data on my website ...I want to build a stock ticker for my website ....would it be legal to do that using the real time data that yahoo provides ?

Comment: Yahoo isn't always real-time, they get their quotes from other places. http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/finance/quotes/fitadelay.html

Comment: "figured out how" Usually real live data streams, with 0 delay are protected by **HEAVY** security measures. I find it hard to believe you've got something that isn't at least 15 minutes delayed here.

Comment: @fredley - I think he means real-time from Yahoo... which is already delayed by 15 minutes.

Comment: Look at the bottom of the page, "By accessing the Yahoo! site, you agree not to redistribute the information found therein."

Comment: @Jason - Post that as an answer

Comment: Is this really off-topic? As a cloud programmer, I would like to know these legality issues too. If people can ask about the implications of GPL, LPGL, Apache2, etc, then someone should be able to ask this question. Why discriminate against Yahoo's legalities  in favour of GPL, LGPL's? Otherwise, where could I find answers and discussions on legalities that affect me as a cloud programmer? Please, I beg, allow these questions because I need to know and if I can do a one-stop-shop for all my programming related questions rather than more frequently google all over.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the bottom of the Yahoo finance page, **"By accessing the Yahoo! site, you agree not to redistribute the information found therein."**

If they find you scraping their site they will most likely block your IP or send you a cease and desist message.